# How to change the proxy of a java application in runtime?

Tags: java, proxy, runtime

Regards, I want to set a new proxy in runtime for my application, is that I'm having problems because I need to access to two services, first I need to get data from an of the services and after to use these data for access at the other service.

I have this:

```
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxySet", "true");
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxyHost", "hostname");
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxyPort", "port");
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxyUser", "user");
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxyPassword", "pass");
```

After I write a new proxy:

```
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxySet", "true");
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxyHost", "hostname2");
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxyPort", "port2");
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxyUser", "user2");
 System.getProperties.setProperty().put("http.proxyPassword", "pass2");
```

When I try to change the proxy again, the first configuration remains. Thanks in advance.